# Hadoop MapReduce Replicated Join

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I need to implement a simple inner join using a replicated join, but I am finding shocking little amount of information on how to do this.

I have one dataset < 1gb that looks like

```
A C
A D
B Y
C D
```

Then I have my input file that looks very similar

```
C Z
B I
A B
D Z
C O
```

I want to do an inner join on the 1st column from my replicated dataset and the 2nd column from dataset so that I get something like

```
A C Z
A C O
A D Z
C D Z
```

Neither the replicated dataset or the main dataset will have duplicate lines

I know I need to set the number of reducers to 0, and that I need to read in the replicated dataset during the setup phase of MAP

But I don't know how to read it in, or where to store the replicated dataset, nor the data structure to read the file in, or how to make the join happen.

I saw some tutorials using a hash map but that would not work as duplicate keys would overwrite each other.

Comment: Do you need to implement exactly replicated join? Why not to intersect datasets using reducer?

Comment: I guess not, just as long as I am able to get that output, I made my own solution which I will post for evaluation @Egor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This I the solution I came up with.
The file I want replicated across all mappers is loaded into the Distributed Cache in my driver Code

```
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new Path(args[3]).toUri(), job.getConfiguration());
```

In my mapper, I declare a hash map of type

```
Map<String, List<String>> adjacencyList = new HashMap<>();
```

In the setup phase in my mapper I read all the files from the distributed cache

```
Path[] pathLength1 = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(context.getConfiguration());
            if(pathLength1 != null && pathLength1.length > 0) {
                for(Path file : pathLength1) {
                    readFile(file);
                }
            }
```

The code for read file is below, I am able to bypass the keys overwriting each other by appending all values of the same key to themselves

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath.toString()));
        String stopWord = null;
        while((stopWord = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splited = stopWord.split("\\s+");
            List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
            if(adjacencyList.containsKey(splited[0])){
                temp = adjacencyList.get(splited[0]);
            }
            temp.add(splited[1]);
            adjacencyList.put(splited[0], temp);
        }
```

Then in the math phase when I read my other file in line by line, I can check my hash map if the key exists and join on that.

No reducer required